# Rails 4 nested attributes multiple records when updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm stuck and I don't know why it is not working right.
I have a model product which has many tags.
When I update the product rails update properly the products attributes but is creating another tag record instead of just updating it.

here is my code:

View form:

```
 <%= form_for ([@product.user, @product]), id: 'edit_form' do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
      </div>
    
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.fields_for :tags do |t| %>
          <%= t.label :name %>
          <%= t.text_field :name %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    
    
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

product model:

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    
      belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "user_id"
      has_many :tags, :dependent => :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true, :update_only => true
    end
```

tags model:

```
 class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :product, :foreign_key => "product_id"
        # before_save { name.downcase! }
    
    end
```

product controller:

```
 def edit
        user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @product = user.products.find(params[:id])
        @tags = @product.tags.all
    
      respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end 
      end
    
      def update
          user = User.find(params[:user_id])
          @product = user.products.find(params[:id])
          @tags = @product.tags.all
        
        respond_to do |format|
          if  @product.update(product_params)
            format.html { redirect_to([@product.user, @product], :notice => 'Product successfully updated.') }
          else
            format.html { render :action => "edit" }
          end
        end
      end

    def product_params
          params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, tags_attributes: :name)
        end
```

Comment: You forgot about tag id field.

Comment: Yes. If you do not create id field it will display forms for tags but won't recognize them as existing ones.

Comment: What more I'd say you should drop numeric id and set label as primary key. Then you will never get duplicate tags.

Comment: I have changed the code like that, but still duplicate records...

    <%= f.fields_for :tags do |t| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= t.label :name %>
      <%= t.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

Comment: Sorry but can you show me how you do that?

Comment: could you update your question including how you are setting tags to product? I mean your form for that

Comment: I have a similar example working here http://first-box-8593.sae1.actionbox.io:3000/items/1/edit

Comment: And I have the same as you have in `fields_for`

Comment: I don't have a tag form

Comment: you could try with `f.fields_for :tags, @product.tags`, just to test if that works for you but I can't explain why what you have is not working.

Comment: Yes, not working. When i hit the update button, rails double the tags in database. it's weird

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to pass the tag id in the permit params in your controller

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, tags_attributes: [:id,:name])
end
```

Comment: Glad you have it to work... Remember to mark your question as answered. Have swing !