# I Can't Save Model ( Rails4 )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I Can't save model.

Company Model : Document Model = 1:N

Use a JSON, I wonder cyaan get params of Documents.
But I don't get it.
Does it understand where is bad? 
Please let me know.

Post Data

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "address": "asd",
  "phone": "0394564",
  "fax": "168465",
  "mail": "mailtest",
  "documents":[{
    "name": "name",
    "address": "asd",
    "phone": "58465",
    "fax": "543543"
},{
    "name": "test",
    "address": "asd",
    "phone": "5452452",
    "fax": "24534535"
}]
}
```

Code
[Model]company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :documents
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents
end
```

[Model]document.rb

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

[Controller]company_controller.rb

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(company_params) 

  if @company.save 
    render json: @company, status: :created
  else
  render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end

end

def company_params 
  params.require(:company).permit(:name, :address, :phone, :fax, :mail, documents_attributes: [:name])
end
```

LOG example

```
Started POST "/api/v1/companies/" for 192.168.1.19 at 2014-06-04 21:32:46 +0900
Processing by Api::V1::CompaniesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"name", "address"=>"asd", "phone"=>"12345", "fax"=>"12345", "mail"=>"mailtest", "documents"=>[{"name"=>"name", "address"=>"asd", "phone"=>"12345", "fax"=>"12345"}, {"name"=>"name", "address"=>"asd", "phone"=>"12345", "fax"=>"12345"}], "company"=>{"name"=>"name", "address"=>"asd", "phone"=>"12345", "fax"=>"12345", "mail"=>"mailtest"}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "companies" ("address", "created_at", "fax", "mail", "name", "phone", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["address", "asd"], ["created_at", "2014-06-04 12:32:46.583770"], ["fax", "12345"], ["mail", "mailtest"], ["name", "name"], ["phone", "12345"], ["updated_at", "2014-06-04 12:32:46.583770"]]
   (3.8ms)  commit transaction
```

Comment: Do you get eny errors in the response?

Comment: Do your params come in the form { "company": { ... } }

Comment: Get no Error , add LOG example.

Comment: In your `POST Data` section, the nested attributes appear to be under the `petshops` field. In your strong parameters declaration, they are called `documents_attributes`, and in your log, they appear to be just `documents`. This is probably (the beginning of) your problem. These should all be `documents_attributes`.

Comment: post add "company:"　ParamsParser::ParseError

Comment: Sorry.The petshop was changed into the document.

Comment: @user3710808 - it has to be `documents_attributes`. Could you show your form view as well?

Comment: It seems to be saving everything except for the documents data. Perhaps try using the :autosave on the Company model's association.

`has_many :documents, :autosave => true`

Comment: I try to add belongs_to :company :autosave => true. but It was not able to do.

Comment: View is not making. 
Is it necessary to make?

Comment: @Shinya - It is not, if youa re sending it with AJAX without a from. Still, it has to be `documents_attributes`, not `documents`. Also you need to update your company params, as it only allows name od the document.

Comment: I sent param use a "Postman[Firefox addin]" for a test.Not use Ajax.Even if it grants a permission to a other element , can't get it.documents_attributes: [:name, :adress, :phone, :fax]

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare object as long as you are requiring it in the strong params.

```
{"company"=>{"name"=>...}}
```

Rails will catch the "company" value and permit them.

Same problem here:

[Why isn't my Rails API saving anything to the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049463/why-isnt-my-rails-api-saving-anything-to-the-database/24049546#24049546)

Edit:

In your params:

```
..
"documents":[{
..
```

In your permits:

```
   documents_attributes:
```

Maybe this is the reason.

Related info:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through

[Rails 4 nested attributes multiple records when updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565296/rails-4-nested-attributes-multiple-records-when-updating)

Comment: thx! I try this format.  It was not able to do too. bud I got a param parmit error. I think that it leads to solution.

Comment: I'm gonna add more info to this answer.

Comment: It has solved. Thanks Developers & Scholars. The JSON Format of the cause was bad.